# Is it possible to skip a save but not throw an error with a Rails validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, save

The question sums it up. Is it possible to have a custom validation respond by simply not saving a record, rather than throwing an error? As far as I know, the only way to write a custom validation is by invoking an error like this:

```
def at_least_one_attribute_has_changed
  if no_changes?
    errors[:base] << I18n.t("activerecord.errors.messages.we_did_not_detect_any_changes")
  end
end
```

Perhaps there's a gentler method? Some mystical `skip_save` call that I'm unfamiliar with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you specifically want to have validation fail without a message, or do you want to try to save an object and fail without errors if the object is invalid?

For the former you may be out of luck, the `.valid?` call checks for errors on an object, so if you don't have any messages the object will count as valid.

For the latter you could clear the errors or reload the object if save fails, whichever is appropriate to your use case.

```
unless @object.save
  @object.errors.clear # if object has had attributes changed this will preserve those changes but remove the errors.
end
```

If you provide more information on why you want to do this there may be a more appropriate response.

Comment: My goal is to quietly skip a save if no changes were made to the record. Unfortunately, clearing all errors would be too heavy-handed in this instance, as other validations still might throw relevant errors. I'm curious about this second option you describe, reloading the object if the save fails. Might there be a way to check for a specific error, then reload the object if that error was triggered?

Comment: You can do that, for example: `@object.reload unless @object.errors[:attribute].blank?` . But I would caution you to consider the fact that you are making a save call on an invalid object that hasn't changed, if an unchanged object has errors but you want to save it anyway, should you be skipping the validations instead? Also, you can check if an object has changed with `object.changed?` - might be useful?

Comment: Doubly useful. Thanks for all the advice, Matt!